# Python Hashing with lists

Tags: python, hash

I need some help making a insert function that adds values into a hash table where each table position is a list. If there is collision the value just gets added to the list at the right position.

```
class MyChainHashTable:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.slots = []
        for i in range(self.capacity):
            self.slots.append([])

    def __str__(self):
        info = ""
        for items in self.slots:
            info += str(items)
        return info

    def __len__(self):
        count = 0
        for i in self.slots:
            count += len(i)
        return count

    def hash_function(self, key):
        i = key % self.capacity
        return i

    def insert(self, key):
        #need help 
        #this should insert each value into seperate lists, and if there is collision
        #it should add the value to make a list with +1 positions. 
        #eg. [26][][54, 93][][17, 43][31][][][][][][][77, 90]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def insert(self, key):
    self.slots[self.hash_function(key)].append(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a dictionary for this:

```
def insertWithChain(dict, key, value):
    if key in d:
        d[key].append(value) # add value to an existing list
    else:
        d[key] = [value] # new value in a new list by itself
```